# all mongoose queries stall

Tags: express, mongoose

From previous answers this probably has something to do with my connection but I can't seem to place how to find the issue. I have a few segment of codes that looks like this and the result is a stall after any model function is called

connection - prints success when the server starts

```
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', { useMongoClient: true, promiseLibrary: require('bluebird') })
  .then(() =>  console.log('connection succesful'))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

model.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var holdingsSchema = new Schema({
    pair: String,
    amount: Number
});

var holdingsModel = mongoose.model('holdingsModel', holdingsSchema);
module.exports = holdingsModel
```

and api endpoint

```
 holdingsModel.find(function(err, results) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('there is an error')
        }
        return res.json(results);
    }).then(results => console.log('the results: ' + results));
});
```

At the end of everything I receive an err: empty response.

Answer (score 0):

`find()` needs a [criteria object](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-find). The second argument is the callback. When you are using promises you don't need the callback. Finally, you have to handle the errors with `catch()`.

```
holdingsModel.find({ pair: 'test' }).exec()
   .then(results => res.status(200).json(results))
   .catch(err => res.status(400).json(err));
```

The `exec()` is used to return a proper promise, as mentioned [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html).

Comment: Thanks for checking into it. I tried updating the find method to what you have here but still seeing the empty response on the client end.

Comment: It may not be in the right direction but I am wondering if there is some way to check whether the connections are still valid?

Comment: @massphoenix Yes, you can listen to the connection events. See [this](http://theholmesoffice.com/mongoose-connection-best-practice/) article. You need the `mongoose.connection.on` stuff. You also have to change `{ pair: 'test' }` to a proper query of course. `{}` to return everything in that collection.

Comment: Thanks @MikaS. I am still not totally sure where the problem was but I scrapped everything in my app.js that had the word mongoose and set up connections as in that article which got everything up and running.